# Outlook /importPRF stalls with dialog if the MailboxName in the profile is prefix of another

Tags: active-directory, outlook-2010

I am using a powershell script to make some exporting from various Exchange mailboxes. The main point consists of creating a profile for each affected mailbox and invoke `outlook.exe /importPRF customprofile.prf` and so on.
The main logic and everything works fine, but one problem occurs: If usernames are prefixes of one another (say I have "Foo" and "Foobar") then the profile for the shorter ("Foo") interrupts the automated script and instead a dialog window pops up whether I want to have "Foo" or "Foobar". The name enters into the profile file `customprofile.prf` in form of `MailboxName` lines

```
[Service List]
ServiceEGS1=Exchange Global Section
Service1=Microsoft Exchange Server
...
[ServiceEGS1]
MailboxName=Foo
...
[Service1]
MailboxName=Foo
...
```

What can be done so that no `Foo` vs. `Foobar` question pops up?
In other words: It seems that "Foo" is really interpreted as something like a regex "/Foo.*/". How to make "Foo" really stand for "/^Foo$/" (though of course no regexes can be entered  there)

(In case it is important: the usernames are the `SamAccountName` taken from Active Directory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it looks weird, but in order to avoid the ANR (automatic Name Recognition) you have to prefix the mailboxname with an equals sign `=`

For example

```
MailboxName==Foo
```

Comment: Excellent! Works like a charm.